# Ambiguous quadratic

Tags: functional-analysis

Let there be a complex number z

$$F(z)=z^2 + z +1$$

$$F(z)=0\; \text{ at } \; z=(-1+√3i)/2 \quad \text{ and } \quad z=(-1-√3i)/2$$

$F(z)$ can also be written as $(z+√z+1)(z -√z +1)$.

Therefore, $F(z)=z^2 + z + 1=0$  when $z+1=√z$ or $z+1=-√z$ according to the previous expansion of F(z) as 
$$(z+√z+1)(z -√z +1).$$

Therefore,  $z^2 + z + 1=0$  when $z+1=√z$ or $z+1=-√z$

$$z^2 +√z=0 \text{ or } z^2 - √z=0.$$

In Either of the cases , whenever $√z=0$ , 
$$z^2 + z + 1=0 $$

Therefore, squaring on both sides of $√z=0, z= 0$ must be a root of $F(z)$.

Which is not true.

Comment: From where come : $z^2+\sqrt{z}=0$ and $z^2-\sqrt{z}=0$ ?

Comment: Also, yes, if you suppose that $\sqrt z = 0$ then of course you're going to get $z = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong.

You argue that for a complex root $z$ you'll get $z^2=\pm\sqrt z$

Ignore for a moment the problems with defining $\sqrt z$, that's not the issue here.

the real problem is that you then want to use the converse statement.  That is, you want to assert that any solution to $z^2=\pm\sqrt z$ is a root of the original quadratic.  This, as you point out is false ($z=0$ is a counterexample, as is $z=1$)

Indeed, squaring your equation(s) yields $z^4=z$.  Excluding $z=0,1$ you just get the complex roots you are already aware of.

To be precise, to deduce that $z^2=\pm\sqrt z$ you invoke the fact that $z^2=-(z+1)$.  But this is only true for roots of the original quadratic (tautologically).  In particularly, it is not true for $z=0$.